# Why $\mathbb{CP}^1 \cong S^2$?

Tags: projective-space

Consider $\mathbb{CP}^1 =\frac{\mathbb{C}^2\setminus \{ 0\}}{\mathbb{C}^*}$, one dimensional projective Hilbert space. I was wondering if someone could help me about proving  $\mathbb{CP}^1 \cong S^2$

Here $\mathbb{C}^*$ acts on  $\mathbb{C}^2\setminus \{ 0\}$, so we can construct $\frac{\mathbb{C}^2\setminus \{ 0\}}{\mathbb{C}^*}$.

Comment: What you described is ${\mathbb C}P^0$, not ${\mathbb C}P^1$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Sorry, I meant $\frac{\mathbb{C}^2\setminus \{ 0\}}{\mathbb{C}^*}$.

Comment: Ok, what does the symbol $\cong$ stand for? Is it a homeomorphism, a diffeomorphism, a biholomorphism? And tell us what do you know about this problem (which is a standard exercise in several areas of math).

Comment: @MoisheKohan I think the symbol $\cong$ denotes a diffeomorhism. I am a student in physics and I'm stuying symmetris in quantum mechanics. The underlying space in quantum mechanics is the projective Hilbert space $\mathbb{P}\mathcal{H}=\frac{\mathcal{H\setminus \{ 0\}}}{\mathbb{C}^*}$ and I'm reading a book in which the author mentioned this problem. I don't know a reference about it and I really appreciate if you could introduce me a good reference about projective spaces and $\mathbb{CP}^n$. Thank you.

Comment: @Mahtab Look at this [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/458102/diffeomorphism-of-mathbbcp1-and-s2).

Comment: @SachchidanandPrasad Thank you very much for the link.